# iOS why does this property needs to be strong

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a property which I thought could be weak. But it doesn't display unless it is set to strong.

This:

```
- (void) setTimeAndLocation:(Message *)activity{
    __weak NSString *time = [[[activity getPropertyByPath:@"StartTime"] value] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
    NSLog(@"Time: %@", time); // null

    __strong NSString *time = [[[activity getPropertyByPath:@"StartTime"] value] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
    NSLog(@"Time: %@", time); // works, 20:30

    __weak NSString *time = [[activity getPropertyByPath:@"StartTime"] value];
    NSLog(@"Time: %@", time); // works, 20:30:00
}
```

Is this because substring creates a new string or something like that? I know I don't have to add the __weak or __strong but this is for me very helpful to understand what everything does

Comment: i dont get it. where are you using __strong in your example?

Comment: The updated example will not compile. :-)

Comment: Because of the multiple time variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` is a local variable, not a property.

Generally, all local variables are `__strong` (which is the default when you omit the modifier) because they are automatically disposed when they go out of scope.

You never declare a local variable `__weak` for a newly created object, because the object will be destroyed as soon as it is created. I suspect that `substringWithRange:` creates a new object, as you mention.

The fact that the second one works is misleading. When you declare a local variable `__weak` you have no guarantees that it will be available unless you know you are accessing an object that is strongly retained elsewhere. The variable should be `__strong` (no modifier) in both cases.

---

`__weak` is used when you want to create a weak local variable of a previously created object that is strongly referenced elsewhere. Typically, you use `__weak` variables if you wish to avoid retain cycles inside retained blocks.

Comment: Your second piece that is what I am doing here Or at least trying

Comment: @MouNtant This is the correct answer. If you want to learn more about `__weak` and `__strong`, see Apple's to the LLVM documentation.

Comment: But should it be __strong when you know that activity is strong elsewhere?

Comment: __weak doesn't change the number of references on the object. As soon as the reference count goes to 0, the object is destroyed. If you put __strong (or nothing) you increase the reference count by 1.

Comment: @Geraud.ch Pedantic: reference counts never go to 0. Change "reference count goes to 0" reference count would go to 0".

Comment: @MouNtant Yes, it should be strong, you don't save anything by declaring local variables as `__weak` when there's no need.